# How to send a list of models to a controller using a form POST in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to send to my controller an IEnumerable(ICustomModel) via POST in my view. This is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
    //This just gets me a Dictionary of <Views,Models> that I will use to render partal views,
    var forms = CustomFormUtil.GetCustomMetaPartial2(Model);

    //List of models I want to send to my Controller via Post
    var result = forms.Select(x => x.Model);

}

//I am sendind the IE<ICustomModels>                      
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Service.NewOrderRequest.Index(result), FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        { Html.RenderPartial(form.View, form.Model); }
    }
    <p style="clear: both">
        <input id="submitNOR" type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right" />
    </p>
}
```

And my controller is the following

```
[HttpPost]
    [SaveModelState]
    public virtual RedirectToRouteResult Index(IEnumerable<ICustomMetaModel> forms)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Please fill out the required fields");
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Service.NewOrderRequestForms.Index());
        }
...
```

Debugging I can see in the controller that he is receiving the correct data, but when I click submit, the value of 0 is received.

I am really confused about this behavior.
Is this the best way to pass multiple Models to the Controller?

Comment: You cant bind to an interface. The first thing that happens in the model binding process is that the model(s) are initialized (internally using `Activator.CreateInstance()`). How would it know which concrete type to initialize? Unless you create a custom `ModelBinder` and pass additional properties indicating the type, this simply cant work.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I will try another solution and post it later.

Comment: I have been racking my brains trying to understand what you trying to do. I can't, but I suspect your going about this all wrong. Create a view model containing properties for each model, set the properties if applicable in the GET method, and in the view, if they are not null, use `@Html.Partial()` or `Html.Action()` to render the controls associated with the model. Then post back the view model.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you getting interested. Let me explain you my problem: I have a view that renders multiple/dynamic partial views ( these views are selecting depending on the package that the user previously selected ), all of these partial views have different models and I need to submit them in one big "parent " form. My main concern is what should the controller receive?, since I have multiple and variable models (depending of what the user choose) that are being send from the form.

Comment: I am posting another question regarding these question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908493/what-the-controller-should-receive-when-i-am-sending-a-view-that-contains-multip